# PHP Call constructor once

Tags: php

Im very new to OOP and i'm trying to call my constructor once.

I have a class with a constructor that have a Guzzle client and it also login on a website. Now i have 2 other Classes: Orders and order that is extending the class with the constructor(I'm not sure if im doing it right), i did this because i thought this will call my constructor once but it still creates multiples clients

My code look like this:

RequestController.php: (The constructer with that makes a guzzle client)

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Scraper;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

class RequestController extends Controller
{   
    public static $_instance = null;
    public  $client;

    public function __construct(){
        $headers = [
            'user-Agent' => '',
            'Host' => 'orders.example.com',
            'Origin' => 'https://orders.example.com',
            'Referer' => 'https://orders.example.com',
        ];

        $form_params = [
            'form_params' => [
                'username' => env('USERNAME'),
                'password' => env('PASSWORD'),
                'login' => 'true',
                'language' => 'en'
            ]
        ];  

        $this->client = new Client([
            'headers' => $headers,
            'cookies' => new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar
        ]);

        echo 'new client has created <br>';

        $this->client->post('https://orders.example.com/', $form_params);

        return $this->client;
    }   
}
```

OrdersController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Scraper;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\Scraper\RequestController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Scraper\OrderController;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;
// use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class OrdersController extends RequestController
{   
    public $order_ids = [];

    public function orders(){
        $response = $this->client->post('https://orders.example.com/orders/orders');
        $crawler = new Crawler((String) $response->getBody());

        $order_ids = $crawler->filterXPath('//tbody[contains(@class, "wide")]')->extract(['_text', 'rel']);

        foreach($order_ids as $order_id){
            $order = new OrderController();
            $order->order(substr($order_id[1], 2)); 
        }
    }
}
```

OrderController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Scraper;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\Scraper\RequestController;

class OrderController extends RequestController
{   
    private $_delivery_time,
            $_order_price,
            $_delivery_price,
            $_total_price,
            $_pay_option;

    public  function order($order_id){
        $details = [
            'form_params' => [
                'id' => $order_id
            ]
        ];  

        $response = $this->client->post('https://orders.example.com/orders/details', $details);

        // echo (string) $response->getBody();

        // die();

    }
}
```

If anyone could give me some advice i would really appreciate it, Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

> Note: Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to parent::__construct() within the child constructor is required. If the child does not define a constructor then it may be inherited from the parent class just like a normal class method (if it was not declared as private).

In other words, if you do not define a constructor, your class will inherit it's parent's constructor

```
class Animal {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "Animal instance";
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    public function bark() {
        echo "woof";
    }
}

$dog = new Dog();

//Output will be Animal instance
```

vs.

```
class Animal {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "Animal instance";
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "woof";
    }
}

$dog = new Dog();

//Output will be woof
```